# Possible to tie Google API Key with a Google Apps account?

Tags: api, key, google-apps, api-key

I am trying to get an API key for [Google AJAX Feed API's](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/signup.html). However, it will only let me login with my Gmail (Google account), and I don't see any way to login with the Google Apps account here.

Couldn't find anything related on Google or Lycos. So is it possible to tie the AJAX Feed API key (which I believe will let me access other APIs as well) to my Google Apps account instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail mail addresses are linked to a Google account by default, but Google Apps mail addresses aren’t.

You’ll have to [sign up for a ‘Google Account’](https://www.google.com/accounts/NewAccount) using your Google Apps email address. After that, you’ll be able to login using your Google Apps email.